# Check if Parse.com column Array contains current username

Tags: xcode, swift, parse-platform

I am trying to check if the array in parse contains the current users username:

```
var thisUser = PFUser.currentUser()?.username
```

Query:

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "currentUploads")
            query.whereKey("reportedBy", containsString: self.thisUser)
            query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock({ (object: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
                if (error == nil){
                    // Success fetching user in reportedBy field
                    println("User found")
                }
                else
                {
                    println(error)
                    println("User NOT found")
                }
            })
```

[image]

It gives me error:

> [Error]: $regex only works on string fields (Code: 102, Version:
>   1.8.0) Optional(Error Domain=Parse Code=102 "$regex only works on string fields" UserInfo=0x7fba6a5b7610 {code=102, temporary=0,
>   error=$regex only works on string fields,
>   NSLocalizedDescription=$regex only works on string fields}) User NOT
>   found

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [`equalTo`](https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFQuery.html#//api/name/whereKey:equalTo:) instead of `containsString`. As the error says, `containsString` only works with Strings and not with Arrays:

```
query.whereKey("reportedBy", equalTo: self.thisUser)
```

The name is missleading but the `equalTo` checks all array-elements if they are equal to your string.

Comment: I just tried that myself, and it just gives me "User found", but the column is empty: http://s9.postimg.org/ikrw0buwf/Screen_Shot_2015_10_20_at_12_54_23.png - So how can that be, when i am going to check if the column contains the current username?

Comment: Are you sure that you have a current user?

Comment: Yes, because if i do: `println(PFUser.currentUser()?.username)` i get output: `x8CKAPH4SUhypWW6fBiQHuDHL` - And that it the current username.

Comment: Have you checked what is actually returned? What is the value of `[AnyObject]?`?

Comment: @ØyvindHauge - Weird. When i run `println(object)` i get `Optional([])` as output..

Comment: @IdaEmilie that sounds about right to me :) Nothing is returned since the username is not in the array. You will not get an error on empty results. An error will be returned only if the query actually failed (e.g. if your network connection is down).

Answer (score 0):

Given that you should use `equalTo` instead of `containsStringIt`, it will not be weird that you get an empty object. That should be correct if your username is not in any of the arrays. I think you believe if no record is found, you should get an error but that is not the case. You simply get an empty object back if nothing is found.